# Почему не работает onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Честно, не могу разобраться почему не работает `onClick`

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react'; 
import  {Navbar, Nav, FormControl, Container, Form, Button, Modal} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Route,BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from './logo192.png';

import Home from '../Pages/Home';
import AboutScholl from '../Pages/AboutSchool';
import Infrastructure from '../Pages/Infrast';
import ForStudents from '../Pages/ForStudents';









export default class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            show: false
        }
    }
    
    handleShow = () => {
        this.setState({show: true});
    }
    
    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({show: false});
    }


    render() {

        return (
          <>  
            <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="md" bg="dark" variant="dark">
                <Container >
                    <Navbar.Brand href="/">
                        <img 
                            src={logo}
                            height="30"
                            width="30"
                            className="d-inline-block align-top"
                            atl="logo"
                        /> NameSchool
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-naw" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav" >
                        <Nav className="mr-auto">
                            <Nav.Link href="/"> Главная </Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="/aboutScholl"> О Школе </Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="/forStudent"> Обучающимся </Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="/infrastructure"> Инфраструктура </Nav.Link>
                        </Nav>
                        
                        <Button variant="outline-info" className="mr-2" onClick={this.handleShow}>Логин</Button> 

                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>

            <Modal open={this.show} onClose={this.handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>Логинься</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Form>
                        <Form.Group controlId="fromBasicEmail">
                            <Form.Label>Туточки ведите почту</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Введите почту" />
                            <Form.Text className="text-muted">Почта выдавалась в школе</Form.Text>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="fromBasicPassword">
                            <Form.Label>Туточки ведите пароль</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" />
                            <Form.Text className="text-muted">Пароль выдавался в школе</Form.Text>    
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="fromBasicCheckbox">
                            <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Запомни меня" />
                            
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form>
                </Modal.Body>

            </Modal>



            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path="/aboutScholl" component={AboutScholl} />
                    <Route exact path="/forStudent" component={ForStudents} />
                    <Route exact path="/infrastructure" component={Infrastructure} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
          </> 
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.state.show`

Comment: Не помогло,при нажатие на эту кнопку ничего не происходит (

Comment: `<Modal open={this.state.show} onClose={this.handleClose}>` сюда прописали?

Comment: да,прописывала туда,помогло,когда заменила open на show,не знаю почему

Comment: потому что компонент `Modal` принимает свойство `show`, а не `open`, по этой причине